# Repeated elements in an array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been developing a code in javascript that you can select text and adding this selected text in an array. When I select a text, a tooltip button is showed for you to adding this text selected in an array.
However, when I click in this button, for each iteration, it's adding n times the selected text, resulting in an array with repeated elements.

The array is the variable selects.
The code that manipulate the array is this:

```
$("#quote-place").click(function quote() {
    var txt = [null];
    var txtSelected = window.getSelection();
    var txtRange = txtSelected.toString();

    if(txtRange.length >= 2) {
            if (window.getSelection) {
                txt = window.getSelection();
            } else if (document.getSelection) {
                    txt = document.getSelection();
            } else if (document.selection) {
                    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
            }
            selects.push('' + txt);
    }
```

Follow below the full code:

```
<html>

<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        #quote-place { position:absolute;  }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">

    function snapSelectionToWord() {
        var sel;

        // Check for existence of window.getSelection() and that it has a
        // modify() method. IE 9 has both selection APIs but no modify() method.
        if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (!sel.isCollapsed) {

                // Detect if selection is backwards
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
                range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
                var backwards = range.collapsed;
                range.detach();

                // modify() works on the focus of the selection
                var endNode = sel.focusNode, endOffset = sel.focusOffset;
                sel.collapse(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);

                var direction = [];
                if (backwards) {
                    direction = ['backward', 'forward'];
                } else {
                    direction = ['forward', 'backward'];
                }

                sel.modify("move", direction[0], "character");
                sel.modify("move", direction[1], "word");
                sel.extend(endNode, endOffset);
                sel.modify("extend", direction[1], "character");
                sel.modify("extend", direction[0], "word");
            }
        } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
            var textRange = sel.createRange();
            if (textRange.text) {
                textRange.expand("word");
                // Move the end back to not include the word's trailing space(s),
                // if necessary
                while (/\s$/.test(textRange.text)) {
                    textRange.moveEnd("character", -1);
                }
                textRange.select();
            }
        }
    }

    var selects = new Array();
    selects.push("1");

    $(document).ready(function() {
            var selectionImage;
            $('#element').mouseup(function(e) {
                if (!selectionImage) {
                    selectionImage = $('<button>').attr({
                        type: 'button',
                        title: 'Citar Texto seleccionado',
                        id: 'quote-place'

                    }).html("Add").css({
                        "color": "red"
                    }).hide();

                    $(document.body).append(selectionImage);
                }

                $("#quote-place").click(function quote() {
                    var txt = [null];
                    var txtSelected = window.getSelection();
                    var txtRange = txtSelected.toString();

                    if(txtRange.length >= 2) {
                            if (window.getSelection) {
                                txt = window.getSelection();
                            } else if (document.getSelection) {
                                    txt = document.getSelection();
                            } else if (document.selection) {
                                    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
                            }
                            selects.push('' + txt);
                    }
                    document.menu.selectedtext.value = selects;

                }).mousedown(function() {

                    if (selectionImage) {
                        selectionImage.fadeOut();
                    }
                });

                selectionImage.css({
                    top: e.pageY - 30,
                    //offsets
                    left: e.pageX - 13 //offsets
                }).fadeIn();
            });
        });

</script>

</head>


<body>

    <div id="element" class="element" onmouseup="snapSelectionToWord()">
        Hello <b>her</b>e is some &nbsp; <i>nice text</i> Please try selecting some
        <p>Amet elementum, platea porta. Magna eros, pid velit? Pid urna nunc ut, amet duis ultrices vut ac nec mus phasellus tincidunt. Et penatibus augue. Proin ac urna, quis arcu ultrices, ut nunc! Ultrices et hac integer rhoncus a placerat sit? Auctor tristique tincidunt augue amet?</p>

    </div>

    <br><br>

    <form class="menu" name="menu">
        <textarea name="selectedtext" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the deeper sense behind `while (i<1) {`

Comment: @baao, sorry, I have forgotten to retire this while. I was testing before post the code here. I edited now. Thank for attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is inside your function for mouseUp `$('#element').mouseup(function(e)` you have inserted the listener for the other action.

`$("#quote-place").click(function quote()`

Everytime there is a mouse up a new listener for the `quote-place` div is registered, so the second time there are two listener, the third three and so on. You need to move this out of the mouseUp function.

A possible different approach is, since you are adding your element in a dynamic way, to add and remove listeners in a dynamic way, using

```
document.getElementById("quote-place").removeEventListener("click", quote, true);
document.getElementById("quote-place").addEventListener("click", quote, true);
```

A working snippet

```html
<html>

<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        #quote-place { position:absolute;  }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">

    function snapSelectionToWord() {
        var sel;

        // Check for existence of window.getSelection() and that it has a
        // modify() method. IE 9 has both selection APIs but no modify() method.
        if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (!sel.isCollapsed) {

                // Detect if selection is backwards
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
                range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
                var backwards = range.collapsed;
                range.detach();

                // modify() works on the focus of the selection
                var endNode = sel.focusNode, endOffset = sel.focusOffset;
                sel.collapse(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);

                var direction = [];
                if (backwards) {
                    direction = ['backward', 'forward'];
                } else {
                    direction = ['forward', 'backward'];
                }

                sel.modify("move", direction[0], "character");
                sel.modify("move", direction[1], "word");
                sel.extend(endNode, endOffset);
                sel.modify("extend", direction[1], "character");
                sel.modify("extend", direction[0], "word");
            }
        } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
            var textRange = sel.createRange();
            if (textRange.text) {
                textRange.expand("word");
                // Move the end back to not include the word's trailing space(s),
                // if necessary
                while (/\s$/.test(textRange.text)) {
                    textRange.moveEnd("character", -1);
                }
                textRange.select();
            }
        }
    }

    var selects = new Array();
    selects.push("1");

    $(document).ready(function() {
            var selectionImage;
            $('#element').mouseup(function(e) {
                if (!selectionImage) {
                    selectionImage = $('<button>').attr({
                        type: 'button',
                        title: 'Citar Texto seleccionado',
                        id: 'quote-place'

                    }).html("Add").css({
                        "color": "red"
                    }).hide();

                    $(document.body).append(selectionImage);
                }

                function quote() {
                    var txt = [null];
                    var txtSelected = window.getSelection();
                    var txtRange = txtSelected.toString();

                    if(txtRange.length >= 2) {
                            if (window.getSelection) {
                                txt = window.getSelection();
                            } else if (document.getSelection) {
                                    txt = document.getSelection();
                            } else if (document.selection) {
                                    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
                            }
                            selects.push('' + txt);
                    }
                    document.menu.selectedtext.value = selects;
                    document.getElementById("quote-place").removeEventListener("click", quote, true);
                   document.getElementById("quote-place").removeEventListener("mousedown", fadeImage, true);

                }
                
                function fadeImage() {
                    if (selectionImage) {
                        selectionImage.fadeOut();
                    }
                    
                   
                }
                

                document.getElementById("quote-place").addEventListener("click", quote, true);
                document.getElementById("quote-place").addEventListener("mousedown", fadeImage, true);
                
                selectionImage.css({
                    top: e.pageY - 30,
                    //offsets
                    left: e.pageX - 13 //offsets
                }).fadeIn();
            });
        });

</script>

</head>


<body>

    <div id="element" class="element" onmouseup="snapSelectionToWord()">
        Hello <b>her</b>e is some &nbsp; <i>nice text</i> Please try selecting some
        <p>Amet elementum, platea porta. Magna eros, pid velit? Pid urna nunc ut, amet duis ultrices vut ac nec mus phasellus tincidunt. Et penatibus augue. Proin ac urna, quis arcu ultrices, ut nunc! Ultrices et hac integer rhoncus a placerat sit? Auctor tristique tincidunt augue amet?</p>

    </div>

    <br><br>

    <form class="menu" name="menu">
        <textarea name="selectedtext" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I moved the function out of the mouseup function, but don't works. The tooltip button don't appear. Any idea?

Comment: @Marcel I updated the answer with a working snippet and a possible solution